# Called Network Batch with Constant "Path not Found"

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that is located in a shared location. The Batch file is started by another batch file. However, it seems that `PUSHD` or `CD` do not work similarly when the script is started from a shared location by another batch file.

For Example, doing `CD %userprofile%\Desktop` does nothing or states that location can't be found.

Same For `POPD`.

I found a workaround for switching to the desktop by typing in `C:`, click enter, then `CD C:\Users\%username%\Desktop`.

However, `PUSHD` will not work and will either state The system cannot find the path specified when doing `PUSHD %~dp0` or *The Network path was not found* when doing `PUSHD \\server\server\server`.

```
@ECHO ON
::MODE con: cols=100 lines=50


::Custom Data Copying


        ::Copy Chrome Bookmarks
            TASKKILL /f /IM Chrome.exe
            MKDIR "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
            DEL /F /Q "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
            DEL /F /Q "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.bak"
            XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Chrome_Bookmarks" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"


        ::Copy and Rename Sticky Notes
            MKDIR "C:\Users\%username%\Appdata\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Legacy"
            XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Sticky_Notes" "C:\Users\%username%\Appdata\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Legacy"
            REN "C:\Users\%username%\Appdata\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Legacy\StickyNotes.snt" ThresholdNotes.snt


        ::Copy Outlook Signature
            MKDIR "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures"
            XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Outlook_Signature" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures"


        ::Installed Programs List
            XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Installed_Programs\%username%_ProgramsList.txt" %Userprofile%\Desktop
            Start "" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%username%_ProgramsList.txt"


        ::Import Network Drives and List
            Regedit.exe /S "..\..\%computername%\Network_Drives\%username%drives.reg\%username%drives.reg"


        ::Copy Local Ad. Account Pass. Reset
            XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "AdminPass.bat" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"


        ::Import Wireless Connections
            FORFILES /P "..\..\%computername%\Wireless_Networks" /M *.xml /C "cmd /C netsh wlan add profile @path user=all"


        ::WEB LINKS FOLDERS
            C:
            CD C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
            RMDIR /s /q "Web_Links"
            MKDIR "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Web Links"
            XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "\\server\server\server\Web_Links\Win_10" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Web Links"



::Data Collection for Logs

    CLS
    @ECHO ON
    ECHO Current Computer Name is...
    ECHO %Computername%
    ECHO.
    SET /P Adminuser=What is your admin username?

    PUSHD %~dp0

    ECHO %computername%, %date%, %time%, %Adminuser%, %username% >> "..\_Logs\Computer_Names\New_Computers\New_Computers.csv"
    TIMEOUT 2
    POPD
    C:
    CD C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
    GOTO REGFIX
```

The script breaks at the first `PUSHD` and completely stops as well.

Is starting a network batch file by another batch file the major issue here?

Comment: You can't CD to a network path. Pushd maps a drive letter for you. EG `pushd \\127.0.0.1\C$\Windows`. `::` is a malformed label. `rem` is the comment command. See `rem /?` and `goto /?`. `MD` is completely pointless as `XCopy` can make directories. There is no need to change paths in a batch file, it is a user convenience for those typing. Always use full paths.

Comment: @Noodles I am using CD to the local desktop folder under the users profile. PUSHD however does not work once I do C: which switches the drive. I’m aware of the :: and XCopy. I am in the process of cleaning up the batch file which I created two years ago. However, I am basically placing these batch files in a shared location. They will get copied to different locations by different techs which is why I cannot have full paths. That’s why I have PUSHD %~dp0. If I run the script locally it works but starting the script by another script seems to break CD and PUSHD

Comment: That could be because your batch file was called by another batch file. PUSHD may be pushing the current directory that the original batch file is located in. When you say that the second batch file is executed by the first...does the first batch file execute the second like a normal executable batch file or does it use the CALL function? You may want to try using either or rather than what is currently being used.

Comment: @ZachPedigo The second batch is being started and not called. I switched to the call syntax but it still had the same reaction. It uses a drive letter and then the path. Neither PUSHD or CD is able to change it. Unless I do C: and then CD to the desktop but then PUSHD won't work again.

Comment: @FabricioMartinez What do you mean PUSHD won't work again, do you mean that it pushes the wrong directory to the stack or doesn't push a directory at all?

Comment: @ZachPedigo It won't push to a directory. 

The system cannot find the path specified when doing "PUSHD %~dp0"

The Network path was not found when doing "PUSHD \server\server\server"

Comment: Try PUSHD [insert path you want here].

Comment: Looks like you should be able to perform PUSHD on a network drive according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd

Comment: @ZachPedigo yes. It does not work on any device that I am currently testing it on. It is so bizarre.

Comment: Hm, well the PUSHD command itself is meant to push the current directory to a virtual stack. Do you know what directory is being pushed? Try testing by doing PUSHD, pausing the screen with PAUSE, then doing POPD and let me know what directory you end up in. The directory you end up in is the directory that is being pushed to the stack.

Comment: pushd \\Server\Share\path is the syntax for using the PUSHD command with a network drive according to https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-the-pushd-popd-commands-for-quick-network-drive-mapping-in-windows-7/ Have you tried this?

Comment: Keep in mind that doing the above command will result in the first unused drive letter being used to represent the path to the network drive.

Comment: @FabricioMartinez Has your problem been solved? If so please mark the answer as such or request that one of the proposed solutions be posted as an answer.

Comment: @ZachPedigo Hey. Sorry. My health sometimes prevents me from coming back. The issue was not resolved. I could not narrow down what is causing it. What I did was get the script to copy another batch from the shared server to the local device and run it that way. Not the prettiest but it will do. However, I don't know if I should mark the question as answered or not :(

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure XD

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a shot.. Please use as is, do not change anything.

```
@ECHO ON
:# MODE con: cols=100 lines=50
:# Custom Data Copying

    :# Copy Chrome Bookmarks
       cd /D C:\
       TASKKILL /f /IM Chrome.exe
       MKDIR "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
       DEL /F /Q "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
       DEL /F /Q "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.bak"
       PUSHD "%~dp0"
       XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Chrome_Bookmarks" "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
       POPD

     :# Copy and Rename Sticky Notes
        MKDIR "%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Legacy"
        PUSHD "%~dp0" 
        XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Sticky_Notes" "C:\Users\%username%\Appdata\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Legacy"
        POPD
        REN "%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Legacy\StickyNotes.snt" ThresholdNotes.snt

    :# Copy Outlook Signature
       MKDIR "%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures"
       PUSHD "%~dp0"
       XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Outlook_Signature" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures"

    :# Installed Programs List
       XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "..\..\%computername%\Installed_Programs\%username%_ProgramsList.txt" "%Userprofile%\Desktop"
       notepad "%userprofile%\Desktop\%username%_ProgramsList.txt"

    :# Import Network Drives and List
       Regedit.exe /S "..\..\%computername%\Network_Drives\%username%drives.reg\%username%drives.reg"

    :# Copy Local Ad. Account Pass. Reset
       XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "AdminPass.bat" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"

    :# Import Wireless Connections
       FORFILES /P "..\..\%computername%\Wireless_Networks" /M *.xml /C "cmd /C netsh wlan add profile @path user=all"
       POPD

    :# WEB LINKS FOLDERS
       CD "%userprofile%\Desktop"
       RMDIR /s /q "Web_Links"
       MKDIR "%userprofile%\Desktop\Web Links"
       XCOPY /S /H /Y /I "\\spwsrfil003\Deskside\Desktop\Web_Links\Win_10" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Web Links"

:# Data Collection for Logs

    CLS
    @ECHO OFF
    ECHO Current Computer Name is...
    ECHO %Computername%
    ECHO.
    SET /P Adminuser=What is your admin username?

    PUSHD "%~dp0"
    ECHO %computername%, %date%, %time%, %Adminuser%, %username% >> "..\_Logs\Computer_Names\New_Computers\New_Computers.csv"
    TIMEOUT 2
    POPD
    CD "%userprofile%\Desktop"
    GOTO REGFIX
```

Comment: Hi there. Looks like the first PUSHD "%~dp0" returns PUSHD "C:\" instead of pushing to the network location where the batch is located.